# Concatenating unicode character string in python

Tags: python, unicode-string

I have a piece of code where a number of strings are being concatenated like

```
mystring = "%s%s/%s/%s" % (str1, str2, str3, str4)
# str1, str2 and str3 are directory names
# str4 is a file name
```

All was fine until recently this started failing in particular environment.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

I noticed that str1 and str4 are both having unicode character in my case.

```
# str1 is being returned from a db1. It is marked as unicode although
it has only ascii characters. Eg. /mnt/s14691711010z1device1
# str2 and str3 are returned from db2 which are ascii strings only
# Eg. AUTH_5a6625ef15144a1896b420b3374cca39, container1
# str4 is a file name which can be unicode characters in any language
(Korean and Japanese in current case). Eg. file5ßðè
```

Removing either of them from concatenation fixes the failure but that is not what is required.

I am unable to understand why individual unicode string passes but 2 of them together fails. I basically need to construct a file path to check for existence. The values are coming from a db.

What would be the best way to fix this ? My knowledge in unicode is very limited. Should it be something like encode() followed by decode() ?

One easy fix is to type case the str1 as str() since it will contain only ascii characters. But I wish to understand why concatenating 2 unicode character fails while 1 works

Comment: Can you update the question with exact values for `str1` et al. that demonstrate the problem? Also, is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: which version of python do you use?

Comment: Also, there's `os.path.join` for safely building pathnames, or if you have a recent Python 3, there's the new `pathlib`. It's not good practice to concatenate pathnames by hand.

Comment: My guess is that you're using Python 2. Mixing Unicode and non-Unicode strings is not a good idea. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: This is python 2. Will replacing '%s%s' with join() change anything ?

Comment: `from __future__ import unicode_literals` ?